# Why is only one RabbitMQ consumer receiving all the messages when I have two consumer threads going?

Tags: c#, multithreading, rabbitmq

I'm running a test and trying to get two RabbitMQ consumers sharing the pulling of messages from the queue. However, every time I run this, only one of the subscribers/consumers process all of the messages. Why?

I have a separate process that puts 10 sample messages on the queue. I stop that, and then run this.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RabbitReceiver.PullFromQueue(2000));
        Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RabbitReceiver.PullFromQueue(1000));
        Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

And here is the consumer that each thread uses:

```
public static class RabbitReceiver
{
    public static void PullFromQueue(int sleepTimeInMilliseconds)
    {
        string hostName = "localhost";
        string queueName = "Sandbox.v1";

        var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = hostName, UserName = "guest", Password = "guest", Port = 6003 };

        var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        var channel = connection.CreateModel();

        var arguments = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        arguments.Add("x-message-ttl", 864000000); // Not sure why I have to specify this. Got an exception if I didn't.

        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName, durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: arguments);

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

        consumer.Received += (model, eventArgs) =>
        {
            var body = eventArgs.Body.ToArray();
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            Thread.Sleep(sleepTimeInMilliseconds);

            // This should probably go in a finally block.
            channel.BasicAck(eventArgs.DeliveryTag, false);
        };

        channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName, autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens if `BasicQos` is not set. By default, RabbitMQ dispatches all the messages to the first consumer when the message enters the queue. It doesn't look at the number of unacknowledged messages for a consumer.

You can change this behaviour by setting the `BasicQos`, this controls the no of messages a consumer can receive before it acknowledges it.

```
channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
```

Reference: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html

Comment: Thank you. I have another RMQ question, if you have a chance to look: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65308405/279516