# Why is my RabbitMQ consumer receiving all messages when I'm specifying the topic I want to receive?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I have different message types on the queue and I'm trying to create multiple C# consumers that each just take a certain type off the queue.

Apparently, I'm supposed to be able to specify the routing key, like shown here, to get just those messages:

```
channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName, exchange: "SandboxEventBus", routingKey: "MessageEvent");
```

No matter why I try, I get all of the messages from the queue and not just the ones with that routing key. What am I missing?

This is the class:

```
public static class RabbitReceiver
{
    public static void PullFromQueue(string caller, int sleepTimeInMilliseconds)
    {
        string hostName = "localhost";
        string queueName = "Sandbox.v1";

        var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = hostName, UserName = "guest", Password = "guest", Port = 6003 };

        var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        var channel = connection.CreateModel();

        var arguments = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        arguments.Add("x-message-ttl", 864000000); // Not sure why I have to specify this. Got an exception if I didn't.
        //arguments.Add("topic", "MessageEvent");

        channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);

        // Enabling these lines doesn't change anything. It was part of my effort of trying different things.
        //channel.ExchangeDeclare("SandboxEventBus", "topic", durable: true); // topic is case-sensitive
        //channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName, durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: arguments);
        channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName, exchange: "SandboxEventBus", routingKey: "MessageEvent");

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

        consumer.Received += (model, eventArgs) =>
        {
            var body = eventArgs.Body.ToArray();
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            Console.WriteLine($"Message: {message}");
            Console.WriteLine($"{caller} - Pausing {sleepTimeInMilliseconds} ms before getting next message (so we can watch the Rabbit dashboard update).");
            Thread.Sleep(sleepTimeInMilliseconds);

            // This should probably go in a finally block.
            channel.BasicAck(eventArgs.DeliveryTag, false);
        };

        channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName, autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);
    }
}
```

Here is the publishing code. I'm simply publishing two different message types.

```
public class MessagePublisherService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ICapPublisher _capBus;

    public MessagePublisherService(ICapPublisher capPublisher)
    {
        _capBus = capPublisher;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        // This publishes messages. To get the messages off the queue, run the RabbitMQ project in this solution.

        try
        {
            // To have a different event, add this.
            await _capBus.PublishAsync(nameof(SnuhEvent), new SnuhEvent());
            Console.WriteLine($"Published message {nameof(SnuhEvent)}.");

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                //_capBus.Publish(nameof(MessageEvent), new MessageEvent(i));
                await _capBus.PublishAsync(nameof(MessageEvent), new MessageEvent(i));
                Console.WriteLine($"Published message {i}.");
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In catch block of publisher.");
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the queue. Notice each message type shows as a different routing key.

[image]

Here is the RMQ code in Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCap(x =>
        {
            x.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost; Database=Sandbox; Integrated Security=true;");

            x.DefaultGroup = "Sandbox";
            x.FailedRetryCount = 3;
            x.FailedRetryInterval = 2; // CAP will invoke the subscriber again if not finished in N seconds.

            x.UseRabbitMQ(conf =>
            {
                conf.ExchangeName = "SandboxEventBus";
                conf.ConnectionFactoryOptions = x =>
                {
                    x.Uri = BuildRabbitUri();
                };
            });
        });

        services.AddHostedService<MessagePublisherService>();
    }

    public static Uri BuildRabbitUri()
    {
        string protocol = "amqp";
        string userName = "guest";
        string password = "guest";
        string host = "localhost";
        string port = "6003";

        return new Uri(protocol + "://" + userName + ":" + password + "@" + host + ":" + port);
    }
```

Comment: Please read the [RabbitMQ Tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html). Exchanges route messages to queues. There are different sorts of exchanges which route messages in different ways: some use the routing key, but some use other things, such as headers, and some ignore these altogether. It's possible to post messages directly to queues rather than to exchanges, in which case no routing takes please. It's unclear how you're publishing messages, and what sort of exchange "SandboxEventBus" is: we need this information. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: SandboxEventBus is a topic exchange. I can add the publishing code to my post now.

Comment: Also check the RabbitMQ management interface, and make sure that the binding from that exchange to that queue is listed, with that routing key

Comment: Your edited question doesn't help determine whether the messages are being published to

Comment: The published messages make it to the queue. I can see them in the RMQ dashboard. Plus, the consumer gets all of the messages. And that's the issue; I want the consumer to only get by topic/routing key.

Comment: So, two things. I note that there are no messages going through that exchange: is that correct? Also there are 3 bindings from that exchange to that queue: are you receiving and messages which have a routing key which isn't one of those 3?

Comment: I'm still not convinced that the messages are being published to the exchange, and not directly to the queue, and you haven't shown me any code to disprove that theory

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood what [mcve] means. Please read the page linked there -- it means a sample which anyone can run, and which demonstrates your issue. That means that *all* code required to demonstrate your issue must be in your question: we shouldn't have to ask for extra bits

Comment: I also can't see any code which publishes a message with a routing key which isn't "SnuhEvent" or "MessageEvent", and the bindings in your screenshot indicates that both of those will be routed to your "Sandbox.v1" queue, so it's expected that you'll receive messages with both of these routing keys

Comment: After I publish, there are 10 MessageEvent messages and 1 SnuhEvent message on the Sandbox.v1 queue. For the consumer class, I'm trying to get it to just grab the MessageEvent messages from that queue.

Comment: Right, but as you can see from the screenshot you posted, you've got 3 bindings from that exchange to that queue, including for MessageEvent and SnuhEvent. They were probably created by previous runs of your application?

Comment: Correct. I know I'm missing something, man. Are bindings relevant to the consumer pulling just a certain type of message? And if a queue has many types of messages in it, can a consumer pull just one of those types, like what I'm trying? I was assuming that `channel.QueueBind()`, specifying the routing key, was what I needed to do.

Comment: Consumers don't "pull certain types of messages" -- please read the RabbitMQ tutorial here. Exchanges route messages to queues, consumers just read queues. It's up to the exchange what it decides to deliver to your queue. QueueBind is a helper method which pokes the RabbitMQ API to set up a new binding between an exchange and a queue: presumably if there's an existing binding already, it doesn't remove it, just adds a new one

Comment: Ok, so that's my issue then. I'm trying to do something that can't be done. I'm putting different types of messages on a queue and expecting a consumer to be able to pull just *some* of those types. That's not how it works, right? To do what I want, I need to have a queue for each type? Then I can have a consumer class for each queue?

Comment: If you want to do that, add in your own filtering client-side. RabbitMQ works as I described, with exchanges routing messages to queues, and (normally) a single consumer listening on a single queue. The tutorial explains that better than I can

Comment: Thanks. If you want to post that as the answer, I'll accept.

Comment: So I have two options: have a queue for each message type and create a multiple C# classes to consume each queue, or keep it all on one queue and create a C# class to pull each message and distribute to the appropriate handler. Is one approach better or more widely accepted?

Comment: It depends how you want the queueing to work. Do you need messages to arrive in-order across both routing keys, for instance?

Comment: No, I don't believe order will be important here.